# Understanding x86 syntax regarding a C 'bomb'

Tags: c, assembly, x86, parameter-passing, reverse-engineering

I've been given an executable file written originally in C, that plays a guessing game. I as the player am supposed to guess 5 numbers, and if I do it right, the bomb does not go off. However, as soon as I miss one, I lose and the bomb explodes. My approach to this problem so far has been to disassemble the executable and attempt to read the solution from there. I know that at some point, the *strcmp* function is called, meaning my guess vs. the key value will be stored somewhere before that into a register. What I'm lost on is where to find it, and how to access the correct string of characters storing that number.

Here is the assembler code that I've gotten to:

```
0804856a <main>:
804856a:    55                      push   %ebp
804856b:    89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
804856d:    83 e4 f0                and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
8048570:    57                      push   %edi
8048571:    56                      push   %esi
8048572:    53                      push   %ebx 
8048573:    81 ec 14 02 00 00       sub    $0x214,%esp //prologue code ends
8048579:    8b 35 fc 98 04 08       mov    0x80498fc,%esi
804857f:    83 7d 08 02             cmpl   $0x2,0x8(%ebp)
8048583:    75 18                   jne    804859d <main+0x33>
8048585:    c7 44 24 04 fb 86 04    movl   $0x80486fb,0x4(%esp)
804858c:    08 
804858d:    8b 45 0c                mov    0xc(%ebp),%eax
8048590:    8b 40 04                mov    0x4(%eax),%eax
8048593:    89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%esp)
8048596:    e8 65 fe ff ff          call   8048400 <fopen@plt>
804859b:    89 c6                   mov    %eax,%esi
804859d:    bb 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%ebx
80485a2:    bf e4 98 04 08          mov    $0x80498e4,%edi
80485a7:    3b 35 fc 98 04 08       cmp    0x80498fc,%esi
80485ad:    75 10                   jne    80485bf <main+0x55>
80485af:    89 5c 24 04             mov    %ebx,0x4(%esp)
80485b3:    c7 04 24 fd 86 04 08    movl   $0x80486fd,(%esp)
80485ba:    e8 51 fe ff ff          call   8048410 <printf@plt>
80485bf:    89 74 24 08             mov    %esi,0x8(%esp)
80485c3:    c7 44 24 04 00 02 00    movl   $0x200,0x4(%esp)
80485ca:    00 
80485cb:    8d 44 24 10             lea    0x10(%esp),%eax
80485cf:    89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%esp)
80485d2:    e8 09 fe ff ff          call   80483e0 <fgets@plt>
80485d7:    85 c0                   test   %eax,%eax
80485d9:    74 22                   je     80485fd <main+0x93>
80485db:    8b 14 9f                mov    (%edi,%ebx,4),%edx
80485de:    89 54 24 04             mov    %edx,0x4(%esp)
80485e2:    89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%esp)
80485e5:    e8 56 fe ff ff          call   8048440 <strcmp@plt> //call to strcmp, so the two parameters (my guess vs. key) must be stored before it. 
80485ea:    85 c0                   test   %eax,%eax
80485ec:    74 05                break<main+0x89>
80485ee:    e8 4d ff ff ff          call   8048540 <bomb>
80485f3:    83 c3 01                add    $0x1,%ebx
80485f6:    83 fb 05                cmp    $0x5,%ebx
80485f9:    7e ac                   jle    80485a7 <main+0x3d>
80485fb:    eb 05                   jmp    8048602 <main+0x98>
80485fd:    83 fb 05                cmp    $0x5,%ebx
8048600:    7e a5                   jle    80485a7 <main+0x3d>
8048602:    e8 19 ff ff ff          call   8048520 <success>
8048607:    b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
804860c:    81 c4 14 02 00 00       add    $0x214,%esp //epilogue code begins
8048612:    5b                      pop    %ebx
8048613:    5e                      pop    %esi
8048614:    5f                      pop    %edi
8048615:    89 ec                   mov    %ebp,%esp
8048617:    5d                      pop    %ebp
8048618:    c3                      ret
```

So far on this project I've been using the GNU debugger to try and riddle through the program. However, I can't seem to understand it. This is my first exposure to x86 asm. My theory is that the strings would have to be saved into %edi/%edx/%eax at lines 80485db/de/e2, but I don't understand how those strings would be stored there, not how to get at them. I'd really appreciate any help from more experienced coders, since this has been confusing me for days.

Comment: You have not asked a question explicitly - are you trying to find out the correct sequence of numbers, or patch user input checking code so that it always passes?

Comment: There probably isn't a string of characters storing the correct number.

Comment: Trying to reverse-engineer code before the bomb (which is monitoring your keystrokes) goes off is an even better game ;-)

Comment: In the Apple ][ *Dracula's Castle* game, if you looked at the code with a disassembler or tabulator you could see loads of strings containing hints which were all red herrings - the real stuff wasn't so easily visible.

Comment: If it really is doing a simple comparison to hard-coded strings, you can try running the program [strings](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/strings.html) on your executable.  I.e., `strings <exename>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have correctly identified the critical region around `80485db`. Let's work backwards from the `strcmp` call. It takes two operands to compare, they are put on the stack in the preceding two lines from the registers `%eax` and `%edx`. We can see `%eax` is the return value from `fgets`, which is just the text entered. `%edx` is loaded by `mov (%edi,%ebx,4),%edx` which unfortunately depends on two other registers. `%edi` is the easier one, it is set by `mov $0x80498e4,%edi` to a constant address. `%ebx` is initialized to `1` at `804859d` then incremented at `80485f3` and compared to `5` later. We can thus see it is the loop counter, showing which input we are processing. Putting this all together means `%edx` is loaded from an array containing the expected strings. The first string will be at `0x80498e4+4` because ebx starts out from 1. As such, `x/5s *0x80498e8` in gdb should show you the required input to defuse the bomb.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of help I needed, thank you very much. What confused me was the operations being done on %edi before it was placed in %edx. I was able to figure it out once you explained what that mean, and I thought about how I could trace the contents of the registers back through the code from it. Great preparation for the next assignment, thank you very much.